# Adding Span Tag In WordPress Default Comment Content Form Using JQuery

Tags: wordpress

Be lucky day, ;-), Today, I have difficulties in **adding span tag in wordpress default comment content form by using jquery**. Now, I added my span tag in wordpress comment content form (textarea) by using jquery. It didn't work and didn't show it, But, **when I inspected with firebug, it can be visible in firebug!**

```
<textarea aria-required="true" rows="8" cols="45" name="comment" id="comment"><span>Custom Span</span></textarea>
```

I understand, If I  add only text using jquery, it can work and display, and then, if I edit the core code of wordpress, it can make it work, but, I don't wanna touch the core codes! So, Is there anyways to insert span tag(whatever tag) to put in wordpress default comment content form (textarea)

Comment: please provide your code so we can help. From what i understand, you cannot add a html tag inside a textarea, only text like : <textarea>default text here</textarea>

Comment: So, no ways, to add html tag in wordpress comments content form in textarea, hum? Thanks for your answer!

Comment: unfortunately not. why would you like to add html tags inside a textarea ? colorization ?

Comment: Hello, skiplecariboo, You know, wp admin allow us to add some of the html tags in comment textarea! So, one of my blog, I wanna add only comment for admin!And I don't wanna make my clients adding html code in textarea!, and I really wanna make him add specific html tag dynamically using jquery! Anyway, Thanks, skiplecariboo